# Pivoting on Dates Parameters in SQL for WoW Growth

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, pivot

I am trying to measure and display week over week growth within a SSRS report.

I am trying to use a combination of the pivot function within SQL and parameters to easily retrieve the data I need in SQL without having to add overcomplicated formulas and matrixes in SSRS.

The formula I tried is:

```
SELECT     category, COALESCE (sum([@wedate]), 0) AS currentweek, COALESCE (sum([@wedate-7]), 0) AS previousweek
FROM OfficeProduction 
PIVOT (sum(amount) FOR wedate IN ([@wedate], [@wedate-7])) AS p
WHERE     category = 'Revenue'
GROUP BY category
```

When i try to save this as a stored proc I get errors, as well as when i insert it directly into the dataset box within SSRS.

I have tested inserting values for the parameters

```
SELECT     category, COALESCE (sum([7/7/12]), 0) AS currentweek, COALESCE (sum([6/30/12]), 0) AS previousweek

FROM OfficeProduction 

PIVOT (sum(amount) FOR wedate IN ([7/7/12], [6/30/12])) AS p
WHERE     category = 'Revenue'
GROUP BY category
```

and I get the appropriate result...so i get the feeling im close, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you will need Dynamic SQL to pass in your parameters and execute the final statement with your parameter value. Here is a short quick script that should work:

```
create table t
(
    id int,
    wedate datetime,
    amount int
)

insert into t values (1, '2012-07-07', 50)
insert into t values (2, '2012-06-30', 25)
insert into t values (3, '2012-07-07', 75)
insert into t values (4, '2012-06-30', 25)

DECLARE @wedate datetime
DECLARE @wedateP datetime
declare @sql varchar(max)

DECLARE @wedateCol varchar(10)
DECLARE @wedatePCol varchar(10)

set @wedate = '2012-07-07'
set @wedateP = DateAdd(d, -7, @wedate)

set @wedateCol = Convert(char(10), @wedate, 101)
set @wedatePCol = Convert(char(10), @wedateP, 101)

set @sql = 'select * FROM t
            PIVOT
            (
                sum(amount)
                for wedate in ([' + @wedateCol + '], [' + @wedatePCol +' ])
            )p '

exec(@sql)

drop table t
```

It is creating the week previous value in a separate parameter and then converting those to text values for the PIVOT.

Comment: this is showing signs of working, but I am having issues issues with sql converting the values to strings and back to dates.  Will continue to play around with this method

Comment: Can you post some sample data?  I just guessed on the data in my sample.

Comment: that worked beautifully @bluefeet.  thanks for the help (my original comment was based on your original answer and was before you editted it to the above)

Comment: @user1551957 happy to help, since you are new to SO, please be sure to mark an answer as accepted via the checkmark on the left. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is @wedate-7.  The second column name is [7/7/12-7].

Calculate @wedate_prev and use that in the query.

The calculation would look something like:

```
select convert(varchar(255), dateadd(d, -7, @wedate), 101)
```

Or, better yet:

```
select cast(month(dateadd(d, -7, @wedate)) as varchar(2))+'/' +
       cast(day(dateadd(d, -7, @wedate)) as varchar(2))+'/'+
       cast(year(dateadd(d, -7, @wedate))%100 as varchar(2))
```

Comment: SQl doesn't like any of these within the operators of the pivot function (doesn't quite like @wedate either).